# Prove that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -1$ and verify ideal gas law

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Ok guys, continuing my passage through edwards... here is the question... thanks for hints/solutions in advance:

Suppose $f(x,y,z)=0$ can be solved for each of the three variables $x,y,z$ as a differentiable function of the other two. Then prove that

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = -1$

Verify this is the case for the ideal gas equation $pv =RT$ where (where $p,v,T$ are the three variables and $R$ is the constant).

Comment: Use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68039/simplifying-frac-partial-v-partial-t-cdot-frac-partial-t-partial-p?rq=1

Comment: Triple product rule http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule

Comment: thanks guys... that helps a lot.

Comment: You could also look up the Upstairs-Downstairs, Inside-Out Formula,

Comment: oh god... we did that in my stat-therm class. man... i shoulda went there first

Answer (score 4):

Define $f(x(y,z),y,z)=f(x,y(x,z),z)=f(x,y,z(x,y))=0$. Then by the
chain rule, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} & = & 0\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} & = & 0\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} & = & 0
\end{eqnarray*}
So that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} & = & -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} & = & -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} & = & -\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, 
$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}}=-1.
$$